# Cookie to keep div visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a popup window for users to login and when they sign in the window closes and the parent window reloads like it's supposed to with the user logged in. But, I need a div to remain visible when that happens (it is normally hidden when page loads). I have the following code and it is definitely not working (note: I have `<script src ="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>`). I have looked at many answers but this is my first time doing this and am having trouble. The following code is in the `$(document).ready(function() {` section.

```
window.onunload = divcookie();
function divcookie (){ 
   if($("#div1").is(':visible')){
       $.cookie('divState', 'visible');
   } else {
       $.cookie('divState', 'hidden');
   }
};

window.onload = vis_cookie();
function vis_cookie (){ 
   if($.cookie('divState')=='visible'){        
       $("#div1").show();
   };
}
```

This is the code I have above it:

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div1-link").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#div1").toggle();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first of all**

when you do `window.onload` **within** `$(function() {})` then the `onload` is already over...

**next: if you do**

```
window.onunload = divcookie();
```

the `divcookie` is executed immediatelly and not on unload... (because of the `()`)...

the same will happen with the `onload` callback.

**next:** if you want a cookie to be set, when a div is displayed, do it then, wenn the div was displayed and not on `unload`

```
$("#div1-link").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#div1").toggle();
    $.cookie("divState", "hidden");
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is that the div can also be hidden when user clicks outside the div as well as when the user clicks the button. So I was hoping to do it in a way that when the window is refreshed, it first sets a cookie for whether the div was visible and then when it loads, it shows the div if the cookie was set to visible. I made adjustments to code and it works now. Thanks Luke!